# Multisession burn in Imgburn

Tags: windows, dvd, burning

Is Multisession burn available in Imgburn? If not, any idea whether it will be implemented in future? I almost recommended Imgburn instead of Nero or Roxio to one of my friend. He requires multisession burning and I found no options to enable it,if available in Options.

Note: Please don't question the question. Like, Why would you want multisession anyway? or Isn't USB stick/RW Disk is what you need instead of a RO CD/DVD? Please keep the answers in context. I know that I can use USB sticks instead of CD/DVD and my friend require mulisession anyway. May be I can ask him to keep Nero as a backup for this purpose if Imgburn don't support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=3433) is a lengthy topic in the ImgBurn forums discussing the issue.

Deep down in the thread, [this](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=3433&view=findpost&p=70907) post says its in the works.

Answer (score 3):

Author stated in forum that if you want it feel free to write your own burning software.  This is basic functionality but indications are he is against it for some reason.  Get something else.  There are plenty of free apps out there just as good that also have the BASIC functionality of allowing multisession burning.

Answer (score 0):

As of May [it is not supported](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=9548&st=0&p=88994&#entry88994) per the author.  Elsewhere he has stated he doesn't plan on doing it until [a major rewrite](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=3433&st=40&p=70907&#entry70907).