# What software supports full multisession CD burning on windows?

Tags: windows, burning, compact-disc, session

I know, that beating [Nero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_(software_suite)) in this field is very difficult. I have looked through best software listed in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ISO_image_software), also checked the related posts [here](https://superuser.com/questions/22969/multisession-burn-in-imgburn) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/8634/free-cd-burning-software-for-windows): most of the software either allows you to create ISO image and/or burn the existing image. However I am interested in the following flow:

1. Import previous session
2. Add/rename/remove files and directories
3. Burn new session

[UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/index.html) is very good in (1) and (2). But it cannot append a disk with new session.
[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)/[CDBurnerXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDBurnerXP) can do (1) (2) (3) but:

- InfraRecorder crashes when trying to import some Nero sessions
- CDBurnerXP does not allow to move files in previous session to another directories.

Is anybody here happy with any other free software?

Comment: Free meaning...

Comment: pdvd+rw-tools](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/linux/DVD+RW/tools/win32/)
Not posting as answer because a 2006 dated crosscompiled CLI tool may be too weird for a regular Windows user ;)
But it is *really* free (Hello71!).

Comment: Free meaning FOSS or "no money".

Comment: Nero, I guess. Which is not free. :)

Comment: @whitequark: If I understood correctly, `growisofs` you refer is based on `mkisofs` which can import the previous session and add new files to it. However AFAIK there is no option to remove/rename a file.